# Clips are not linking up end to end

Tags: after-effects

it has been a big while since I have last used After Effects.

Currently I am getting into a problem in which I have a few footages, tried changing the frame rate etc but it does not seems to help.

You can see in the image, the the lower bar clip is not starting right off at the end of the first clip, since the first clip ends off slightly more than the 07f mark.
As such, if I try to add in another clip, it can only be at the 07f or the 08f mark.

Is there anyways that I can make it 'linked' up end to end?

[image]

Comment: This question would get better answers on videoproduction

Answer (score 0):

Just hold Shift button while dragging the second footage.
And to easily change the frame-rate you can use [video copilot frame rate converter](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/frame_rate_converter/)